# WTForms default values by current_user flask-login

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I'm trying to make a few inputs have a default value retrieved from MongoDB, using mongoengine.

But when I'm trying to set a default value like this...

```
# Edit form (wtform)
class EditForm(FlaskForm):
    firstname = StringField('First name', default = current_user.firstname)
    ...
```

... I get an error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'firstname'

How do I solve this issue?

Can I somehow pass "current_user.firstname" by value in .html file?:

```
{{ form.firstname(class_='form-control', placeholder_='First name', value_='current_user.firstname') }}
{{ form.firstname.label(for_='firstname') }}
```

Comment: did you use flask_login ? you should import current_user. `from flask_login import current_user`

Comment: @DhaniPro Yes. I am importing current_user from flask_login. Still doesn't work :(

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by myself. For future reference, all I had to do was to remove '' from value_:

```
{{ form.firstname(class_='form-control', placeholder_='First name', value_=current_user.firstname) }}
{{ form.firstname.label(for_='firstname') }}
```